# Searching a Jquery Cycle Pluggin for Mootools

Tags: jquery, ajax, mootools

im looking for something like this: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/basic.html but made in mootools, do you know about one? :) thxs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slideshow 2](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/)

@Not working in IE. I don't know I don't use IE but the [Slideshow googlecode page](http://code.google.com/p/slideshow/) states

> Slideshow is compatible and fully
>   tested with Safari, Internet Explorer
>   6 and 7, Firefox (and its mozilla
>   friends), Opera and Camino.

Here a few others to test out

[floom](http://blog.olicio.us/2009/07/25/floom/)

[noobSlide](http://www.efectorelativo.net/laboratory/noobSlide/)

[SmoothGallery](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/)

[iCarousel](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/icarousel/)

[BarackSlideshow](http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/barackslideshow/)

Comment: Jitter, I tested Slideshow2, its what im looking for, but doesnt work in IE, see: http://kb.muscarienlinea.com/mo/

Comment: Solved, IE is very strict interpreting JS.

Comment: Then please append problem+solution for others to see on your question

Comment: OK, removing the last comma from "data var" resolves the problem.