# Prototype - Cycle over 4 images using fade effect (sldieshow)

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have been using this plugin for jQuery that allows me to easily cycle over 4 images http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Does anyone know of any simular code that I can use to do this using prototype?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: any reason looking for another

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680930/searching-a-jquery-cycle-pluggin-for-mootools

Comment: code im using uses prototype and not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here, [this one allows](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/flipper.htm) you to put as many as you want in a cycle, each with its own URL.